# Is there a way to get messages from the producer queue buffer in node-rdkafka?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Imagine that connection to a Kafka cluster has closed (e.g. eth cable was cut), and sooner or later the buffer queue is going to get full. How does one get those messages from the buffer and let's say send it to a local storage? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If node-rdkafka cannot send messages that are in the buffer it will expire them after `message.timeout.ms` which is 300000 (5mins) by default. When expiring each message it will emit the `delivery-report` event and pass in the error and the message.

For example, you can set a listener on this event and have some backup logic in case of a failure:

```
// Register delivery report listener
producer.on('delivery-report', function(err, report) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Delivery report: Failed sending message ' + JSON.stringify(report));
        console.error(err);
        // We could retry sending the message or store it locally
    } else {
        console.log('Message produced, offset: ' + report.offset);
    }
});
```

The `report` object contains all the information (body, key, partition) needed to resent it if you want.